# flutter provider MultiProvider using StreamProvider

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, flutter-provider

I am developing a Flutter app using Provider (provider: 3.0.0+1). I am using MultiProvider using StreamProvider with controller. But I am always getting an error.

Below is my code

main.dart

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    StreamProvider<RecipeStreamService>.value(value: RecipeStreamService().controllerOut)
  ],
  child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Home Food',
        routes: {
          '/register': (BuildContext context) => RegisterPage(),
          '/login': (BuildContext context) => LoginPage()
        },
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.lightBlue[300],
          accentColor: Colors.green[300],
          textTheme: TextTheme(
            headline: TextStyle(fontSize: 42.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black54),
            title: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
            body1: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
            button: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, color: Colors.white)
          )
        ),
        home: HomePage(title: 'Home'),
      ),
  );
}
```

RecipeStreamService.dart

```
class RecipeStreamService {
   List<Recipe> _recipes = <Recipe>[];

   final _controller = StreamController<List<Recipe>>.broadcast();
   get controllerOut => _controller.stream;
   get controllerIn => _controller.sink;

   RecipeStreamService() {
      getRecipes();
   }

   addNewRecipe(Recipe recipe) {
     _recipes.add(recipe);
    controllerIn.add(_recipes);
  }

  getRecipes() async{
     List<Map<String, dynamic>> result = await ApiService().getRecipes();
     List<Recipe> data = result.map((data) => Recipe.fromMap(data)).toList();
     data.map((f) => addNewRecipe(f));
 }

 void dispose() {
   _controller.close();
 }
}
```

But I Am always getting this error:

```
type '_BroadcastStream<List<Recipe>>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<RecipeStreamService>'
I/flutter (16880): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (16880): #0      MyApp.build (package:app_recipe/main.dart:20:80)
```

Line: 20:80 in main.dart is (RecipeStreamService().controllerOut)

****** UPDATE ******

Changed Multiprovider to below code

```
 providers: [
    StreamProvider<List<Recipe>>.value(value: RecipeStreamService().controllerOut)
  ],
```

Also in HomePage.dart, where I use it, I have

```
final recipeService = Provider.of<List<Recipe>>(context);
```

Now, recipeService is always coming as null

Thanks

Comment: `controllerOut` doesn't seem like it is a stream

Comment: Hi Remi, but it is defined in RecipeStreamService, get controllerOut => _controller.stream;

Comment: Oh sorry I misread the error. You have a stream of list, and you're trying to assign it to Stream of RecipeStreamService

Comment: Hi Remi, so it should be StreamProvider<List<Recipe>>.value(value: RecipeStreamService().controllerOut)

Comment: Can you try `controllerOut.add` instead of `controllerIn.add` ?
https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are seeing your error is because the **type parameter** you are passing to `StreamProvider<T>` as `T` is not matching what you are *returning to `create`*.

In this case, you want to stream *values of type `List<Recipe>`*.
Therefore, you should also pass that for the generic type:

```dart
StreamProvider<List<Recipe>>.value(value: stream)
```

Where the `stream` is your `List<Recipe>` stream.

---

If `Provider.of<List<Recipe>>(context)` is returning `null` for you, it means that you have not added a value to the stream.

If you want to have something other than `null` before you stream emits a value, you can pass `initialValue`:

```dart
StreamProvider<List<Recipe>>.value(
  value: stream,
  initialValue: initialRecipes,
)
```